# How do I avoid the "some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique"?

Tags: r, zoo

I am trying to find a way to append a column to my zoo object without hitting the warning:

> Warning in zoo(rval, index(x)[i]) :   some methods for “zoo” objects
>   do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique

Suppose I have the following code:

```
a <- read.zoo(data.frame(date=as.Date('2011-12-31') + 0:49, col1=seq(1,50), col2=seq(11,60)), FUN = as.Date)
mon <- read.zoo(data.frame(date=c(as.Date('2012-01-01'), as.Date('2012-02-01'), as.Date('2012-03-01')), mc=letters[1:3], mc2=LETTERS[1:3]), FUN = as.Date)
```

And suppose I would like to attach `index(mon)` to `a` so I can reference it later:

```
a$month <- as.numeric(index(mon[MATCH(as.yearmon( time(a)), as.yearmon(time(mon)))]))
```

What is the proper way to do this so I don't get the warning?

Comment: Firstly, don't use MATCH. This was already covered in a prior answer. Secondly, if you are trying to reduce `a` to year/months then use `aggregate.zoo`, e.g. `aggregate(a, as.yearmon, mean)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I know you discourage the use of `MATCH` but I couldn't think of another way to do it. I don't think I can use aggregate in this case because I am not aggregating. I am not trying to reduce to yearmon, this is just an example of an operation that I am trying to perform on the data. I need the value of the matching column in `mon` table appended to the `a` table and yes, it won't be unique in the a table. The problem is not "just take the yearmon of the date field in `a` and stuff it in the `month` column". What I am showing is just a simple example of a bigger project.

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: The code above gives the right result. The only issue is the warning. Is there a way to get the same result without getting the warning?

Comment: In that case I take back the comment about match.  See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want the numeric value of the Date of the first of the month of the index of `a` unless that year/month does not appear in the index of `mon` and in that case you want NA.

```
mon.ym <- as.yearmon(index(mon))
a$month <- as.numeric(as.Date(mon.ym))[ match(as.yearmon(index(a)), mon.ym) ]
```

An alternative without `match` is:

```
a.ym <- as.yearmon(index(a))
a$month <- ifelse(a.ym %in% as.yearmon(index(mon)), as.Date(a.ym), NA)
```